# How can I pick the value from list of dicts using python

Tags: python

I have a sample dict in the below format. I want to append more values in the `headers`. How should I proceed?

```
data = {'heading': 'Sample Data', 'MetaData': [{'M1': {'headers': ['age', 'roll_no'], 'values': [15, 5]}}, {'M2': {'headers': [], 'values': []}}]}
```

To access, I can try something like - `data['MetaData'][0]['headers'].append('class')`. It works this way but I want to access it via loop.

Comment: What does it mean *"I want to access it via loop"*? What is your desired output? Do you want to change ***all*** the dicts under the `MetaData` key?

Comment: I want to append more values in "headers" key of "M1" and "M2" dict.

Comment: It doesn't work that way though does it? That induces KeyError

Comment: Since the value of "headers" key is a list so I guess it is possible to append items in any list. I modified the solution given by @always-sunny and it works.

`[v["headers"].append("class") for val in data["MetaData"] for v in val.values()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append while looping like this,

```
data = {'heading': 'Sample Data', 'MetaData': [{'M1': {'headers': ['age', 'roll_no'], 'values': [15, 5]}}, {'M2': {'headers': [], 'values': []}}]}

for item in data['MetaData']:
  for key, value in item.items():
    headers = value['headers']
    headers.append('class')

print(data)
```